# How to ssh raspberry pi from the outside of the local network

Tags: ssh, putty, raspberry-pi

I have a little problem with my ssh, I’m trying to ssh my raspberry pi from the outside of the network with the public Ip.

Things I done : - Forward the port 22(TCP) on the router - Change some parameter to the ssh_config and sshd_config

When I try to connect with the public Ip, Putty give me this error(ssh connection refused)

I now my password and username are right because when I use ssh but with local up it works(192.168.1.129).

I thinks I have to change a parameter in the ssh_config to allow connections from the outside of the network.

If you have an idea please let me know Thanks

Comment: From inside the network, does `ssh local_raspberry_ip` work?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Yes it works perfectly

Comment: Ok, then your problem most likely relates the port forwarding at the router.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Thanks,I tried lot of things with the port forwarding but I do not have a conclusive result

Comment: Did you test the access with the outside IP address from within the network? That would need special precautions on the router doing the port forwarding.

Comment: There is a similar question solved here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105080/how-to-remote-to-raspberry-pi-from-outside-local-network